# Group by nested table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following tables

```
[Order]
[Product]
    ProductId
[OrderDetails]
    OrderId
    ProductId
    Quantity
```

I have to use the Order object to get a list containing total product sales grouped by sales

```
public class ProductSales 
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Given a List of Order objects how sould I select its product details and then group the sales by product?

My current code looks like this:

```
return Orders
       .Select(ordeDetail => new {
           Detail = ordeDetail.OrderDetails
                        .GroupBy(w => new {
                            Detail = w,
                             Product = w.Product})
        .Select (group => new ProductSales {
            Product = group.Key.Product, 
            Quantity = group.Sum(r => r.Quantity)
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: How are `Order` and `Product` related?

Comment: I would guess every `Order` is linked to some `OrderDetails` lines, each with their own `ProductId` link to `Product`

Comment: Exactly , like Blindy commented every OrderDetail has a productId, updated question

Answer (score 0):

You would group by the product (either by its ID or just the whole row):

```
return Orders
   .Select(ordeDetail => new {
       Detail = ordeDetail.OrderDetails
                    .GroupBy(w=>w.Product)
                    .Select(w=>new ProductSales {
                       Product=w.Key,
                       Total=w.Sum(prod=>prod.Quantity) })
   })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: in }).GroupBy(d => d.Detail.Product.ProductId) Detail is a EntityCollection<OrderDetail> so no Product instance is available

Comment: Getting there ;) I need to return the list with Product and Quantity ordered, Updated question

Comment: Updated mine too -- not sure why you keep insisting on grouping on something other than the product itself. A `GroupBy` clause isn't a `Select`, it's literally what has to change to get a different "bucket" for your data. With that in mind, you group by the product then select out the product and flatten the product's bucket using `Sum`.

Comment: Maybe another select missing? Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcMusicStore.Models.ProductSales>

Comment: I just copied your initialization format, apparently you named it `Total`, not `Quantity`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12607/discussion-between-marc-and-blindy)